# Multiple transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css

Yesterday I got my problem solved about jquery, which didn't load correctly. Today I struggle with yet another problem: two transitions for one element. The first transition starts when the page has loaded: it fades in. This one actually works when I do not use my second transitions. My second transitions must start whenever someone hovers over the `ul`. The problem is that the hover transitions 'overwrites' the fade-in transition. My jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2cpX6/6/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS rules with the same name override each other, just like any other rule.

Try this:

```
transition: opacity 2s ease-in, color 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

Note that you only need `transition` and `-webkit-transition`, since Firefox and Opera now fully support the unprefixed version, and `-ms-transition` never existed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the same CSS rule for the same ruleset without it being overwritten.  This applies to everything.  For example, if you had:

```
span {
    color: red;
    color: green;
}
```

The spans would be green.  This means that you cannot stack transition rules for the same ruleset.

You can create multiple separate transition rules using a comma.

```
transition: opacity 2s ease-in, color .3s ease-in-out;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/2cpX6/7/

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for your answer and explanation, should have figured this out myself.